# Can't create a directory using mkdir() with 0777 permissions

Tags: php, xampp, mkdir

I have this:

```
<?php
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("test", 0777);
umask($oldmask);
?>
```

but receive the error

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/add/add_site.php on line 27
```

I am on Mac OSX El Capitan using XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you are calling your script through Apache, the apache user must have rights to write on the directory.

In order to do so, first you have to find what user is running apache, for this you may use :

```
ps aux | grep http
```

or

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

When you've found apache user, you can create a writable directory for apache :

```
mkdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/add/apachedir  # create a directory for apache
# for the line below, replace apache:apache by your apache user:group.
chown apache:apache /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/add/apachedir # give directory ownership to apache user
```

Now if you edit your script as such :

```
mkdir("./apachedir/test", 0777);
```

Everything should be working.

Then I'd recommend you to be careful when changing a directory permission to 777, it means everyone can read / write in the folder. This is a bad practice most of the time, and critical when this folder is a son of  apache webroot (any user could write in this directory and could run their code with apache rights).

Comment: Thanks. I want all users to be able to add something to a database (which I have implemented) by filling in an html <form>. I then need a new HTML page for each entry. So is there any way to do this without giving them permissions to the directory?

Comment: @LouisC. Yes there is, use PHP to get the form parameters, and save them into a database. A common SGBD used with PHP is MySQL (a used fork is mariaDB). If you have any issue working with PHP/MySQL, don't hesitate to create a new question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give full permission to you htdocs directory in xampp.